# GAE/Go: Namespace not working

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to store datastore record in namespace `MyNameSpace` with GAE/Go, but the code below not working.

```
import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func Save(c *gin.Context, list []MyStruct) ([]MyStruct, error) {
    r := c.Request
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    ctx_with_namespace, err := appengine.Namespace(ctx, "MyNameSpace")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx_with_namespace, "MyProject")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var keyList []*datastore.Key
    for _, v := range list {
        key := datastore.NameKey("MyStruct", v.ColA, nil)
        keyList = append(keyList, key)
    }

    _, err = client.PutMulti(ctx_with_namespace, keyList, list)

    return list,nil
}
```

This code creates records in the default namespace, not `MyNameSpace`.

Does `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` ignores namespace setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/README.md)

> November 8, 2016
>
> Breaking changes to datastore: contexts no longer hold namespaces;
>   instead you must set a key's namespace explicitly. Also, key functions
>   have been changed and renamed.
>
> The WithNamespace function has been removed. To specify a namespace in
>   a Query, use the Query.Namespace method:
>
> `q := datastore.NewQuery("Kind").Namespace("ns")`
>
> All the fields of Key are exported. That means you can construct any Key with a struct literal:
>
> `k := &Key{Kind: "Kind",  ID: 37, Namespace: "ns"}`

I realized I should explicitly set namespace, but it is very inconvenient. I migrated to use `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore`